# Yocto recipe for scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to create a `yocto` `recipe` for `scikit-learn` package. It depends on `scipy` pacakge. I was able to successfully build the `scipy` package using : https://github.com/gpanders/meta-scipy.

When I run `bitbake python3-scikit-learn`, i am getting the below error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'`

I am executing the commands in the below order.

Once I have cloned/copied the `scipy` recipes and the patches listed in the `meta-scipy`, i am running `bitbake python3-scipy` and the build was successful.

Then, I created a `recipe` file with the name `python3-scikit-learn_0.23.2.bb` and the contents are as below.

```
PYPI_PACKAGE = "scikit-learn"

LICENSE = "BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM  = "file://PKG-INFO;beginline=8;endline=8;md5=40ee42dc5a49f1617c5c78f16c50e065"

SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "20766f515e6cd6f954554387dfae705d93c7b544ec0e6c6a5d8e006f6f7ef480"

inherit pypi setuptools3

#DEPENDS = "${PYTHON_PN}-numpy-native ${PYTHON_PN}-numpy ${PYTHON_PN}-scipy ${PYTHON_PN}-joblib ${PYTHON_PN}"
DEPENDS = "${PYTHON_PN}-numpy-native ${PYTHON_PN}-numpy ${PYTHON_PN}-scipy ${PYTHON_PN}"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "${PYTHON_PN}-numpy ${PYTHON_PN}-scipy"
```

When I run the `bitbake python3-scikit-learn`, i am getting this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'`

Checked the path where the `devshell python3` is looking (`poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/python3-scikit-learn/0.23.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages`), and i can only see the `numpy` package there, but `scipy` package is not there.

`ls` command output :

```
 numpy
 numpy-1.17.4-py3.8.egg-info
 pkg_resources
 __pycache__
 README.txt
 setuptools
 setuptools-45.2.0-py3.8.egg-info
```

Can someone point me on how to include the `python3-scipy` package, so that it will be included/copied to the `devshell`. Or do I need to update/fix something else.

Appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can also run:

```
bitbake -c devshell python3-scipy
```

and see exactly where the recipe is packaging everything into the rootfs. The rootfs is by default this:
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n457

```
IMAGE_ROOTFS = "${WORKDIR}/rootfs"
```

so check out what python3-scipy puts into ${WORKDIR}/rootfs (${WORKDIR} is where you get thrown into after you execute devshell, so just cd into rootfs from there).

If python3-scipy puts it into somewhere that is not on the PATH, you can add that to your path.

you can see how python3-scipy looks for libraries:
https://github.com/gpanders/meta-scipy/blob/1c07824202af668ef1539c3de392cf737c5ba3fd/recipes-devtools/python/python3-scipy_1.5.3.bb#L29

```
# Tell Numpy to look in target sysroot site-packages directory for libraries
LDFLAGS_append = " -L${STAGING_LIBDIR}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/numpy/core/lib"
```

Comment: Thank you Mitchell. In the `python3-scipy` recipe file, I have `S = "${WORKDIR}/scipy-${PV}"`.

Comment: you don't have to change your S variable, by default it is `${BPN}-${PV}`. So in your case it would become `${WORKDIR}/scipy-0.23.2` This however doesn't change where to find the packages, this only changes where the source code is unpacked to.

Comment: to add onto this, what you want to do is find out where the scipy library is located and add that to LDFLAGS_append just like how python3-scipy does it in their recipe.

Comment: Thank you Mitchell for your response. In the `python3-scipy` recipe file, I have `S = "${WORKDIR}/scipy-${PV}"`. 

The WORKDIR in my case is: `poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/python3-scipy/1.3.3-r0/scipy-1.3.3`

I did not see any `rootfs` directory under this folder. 

Under ${WORKDIR}/scipy, i see `scipy` related files including `setup.py` file.

So i need to include this path in the `scikit-learn` recipe file? If so, could you please let me know what i need to specify in `LDFLAGS_append`  variable.

Comment: so I took a bit of a look into the pypi.bbclass and the setuptools3.bbclass, and it looks like the pypi.bbclass simply sets the SRC_URI to come form files.pythonhosted.org, and the setuptools3.bbclass includes python-setuptools that has a line that adds this param, `DISTUTILS_INSTALL_ARGS += "--install-lib=${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages"` (http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-maker/tree/recipes-python/setuptools/python-setuptools_18.1.bb?h=pyro#n23)

Comment: so it looks like python3-scipy is doing what it should be, the reason I suspect is that you don't have python3-scipy in your `DEPENDS` of your recipe.

Are you sure that `${PYTHON_PN}-scipy` properly expands to python3-scipy?

Comment: Here is my recipe file. It has python3-scipy in the DEPENDS.

Comment: `PYPI_PACKAGE = "scikit-learn"
LICENSE = "BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM  = "file://PKG-INFO;beginline=8;endline=8;md5=40ee42dc5a49f1617c5c78f16c50e065"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "076369634ee72b5a5941440661e2f306ff4ac30903802dc52031c7e9199ac640"
inherit pypi setuptools3
DEPENDS = "${PYTHON_PN}-numpy-native ${PYTHON_PN}-numpy ${PYTHON_PN}-scipy ${PYTHON_PN}"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "${PYTHON_PN}-numpy ${PYTHON_PN}-scipy"
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227235/discussion-between-sriks-and-mitchell-dzurick).

Comment: Is there a way to tell scikit's setup.py file to use the prebuilt scipy package?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to build successfully? @sriks